# Redundant text in Rebus puzzles, lately

Tags: discussion, tags, question-quality

A number of Rebus puzzles, lately, have found it necessary to state something akin to:

See Also: `[tag:Rebus]`

Some samples:

[A numerical rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29738/a-numerical-rebus)
[A puzzling rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29737/a-puzzling-rebus-puzzle)
[The recursive reflection of this rebus may be too revealing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29788/the-recursive-reflection-of-this-rebus-maybe-too-revealing)

This links to the exact same place that clicking on the Rebus tag, itself, would link to.  Is there some reason, that I'm missing, for this, or can we remove it from the posts, and stop doing it?  It's just clutter, in my opinion.  There have been also quite a few that simply state to See Also, with a link to the Rebus Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you - I was wondering what this was all about myself.

Comment: It's actually still happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, it's redundant to repeat the tag twice; not sure what purpose that would serve. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I've edited it out from the links you've given; feel free to edit any other instances out whenever you see them.

Comment: I need to start using  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ when declining flags on SQA.se... seriously...

Comment: @corsiKa declined - ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Gotta love the one-armed shrug faces. :P

Comment: ["I could not post the rebus in this short form. Stackexchange software claimed that it was to similar to other rebus posts on this site."](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29737/a-puzzling-rebus-puzzle#comment88408_29737)